# 32-bit and 64-bit Office on the same pc - trouble with MS access database driver

Tags: excel, ms-access, ssis, ms-jet-ace

I received an error while trying to execute an MS SSIS package that contained Excel source:

> "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is  not registered on the local machine".

While trying to install MS Access Database driver 64-bit, and then MS Access Database driver 32-bit, I get two conflicting errors:

> "You cannot install the 64 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you have 32 bit Office Products installed"

and

> "You cannot install the 32 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you have 64 bit Office Products installed"

I guess that on my pc 32-bit and 64-bit versions of office are running.

The interesting thing though is that I see that only MS office 2010 and MS office Viewer 2003 are installed on my machine and the latter through a 2007 compatibility package.

So, my question is probably two fold:

1. Is running the driver the proper way to solve my initial problem?
2. How can I overcome the situation where neither a 32-bit nor a 64-bit can be installed because there exist both 32-bit and 64-bit office versions on my pc.

Please keep in mind that I am not sure what should I uninstall. Office 2010 and MS windows viewer 2003 are running on my pc.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same conflicting error messages when installing the Access Database Engine.

Since I new I had installed a 32bit  office, I installed the 32bit version of  Access Database Engine with this command:

```
.\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet
```

I found this trick here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/

By the way, in my case one of the two error messages was also mentioning that I had installed the click to run extensibility component 64-bit registration.

Answer (score -1):

only one version 32/64bit of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable can be installed.

Download it from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: read this article from msdn https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless, I am not sure whether it is helpful or not. If you mean that I have to run from redistributable either 32-bit version or 64-bit, this is something I have already done without success.